# Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator Xde.exe stops working when clicking on "tools"

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

The emulator works fine except that when I click on the tools button, the lowest one on the button list on the right, it says "Xde.exe has stpped working", like this:
[image]

and when I click into debug, it says this:
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved, by running XdeCleanup.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1, and then create new virtual machines and re-deploy. Problem solved.